# Does the number of atoms per kilogram of a given element decrease as you go up in atomic mass?

Tags: mass, physical-chemistry, atoms, elements

This is kind of straightforward. Because as atoms get heavier, the more protons, neutrons, and electrons they have. I would assume that it would take fewer of them to equal a pound. This seems intuitively true, but is it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - [Avogadro's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) ($N_{\rm A} = 6.02 \times 10^{23}$) is the number of atoms it takes to produce the atomic weight of that element in kilograms.

So if you have $6.02 \times 10^{23}$ atoms of oxygen (15.995 atomic mass) then you have 15.995 g of oxygen.

To get the number of atoms in a pound as you suggest, you can take the ratio of a pound to g, i.e.$\frac{1}{2200}$ , and solve for the fraction of avogadro's number:

$$N_{\rm pound} = \frac{N_{\rm A}}{2.2\,m_{\rm atomic}}$$

Comment: Ehm one mole of oxygen 16kg? Isn't it 16g, grams, instead?

Comment: I agree with @carloc - the mass of $N_A$ atoms of oxygen is (approximately) 16 *grams*. not 16kg. To get a mass of 16 kg of oxygen you need $10^3N_A$ atoms.

Comment: @carloc Thanks - edited

Answer (score 2):

Let's think of atomic mass as $m$ in $\text{kg}$ over $N$ in $\text{number of atoms}$. You specified that we consider the trend as we "go up in atomic mass", so let $m/N$ increase. Its reciprocal, $N/m$, will decrease. $N/m$ is in units of $\frac{\text{number of atoms}}{\text{kg}}$, and this is decreasing, so indeed the answer to your question is "yes". This is a (the?) mathematical argument that supports your physical intuition.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct. To get the number of atoms in 1kg, you divide 1kg by the mass of one atom $=\frac{1kg}{massOf1Atom}$. The numerator is here is just a constant. So the larger the denominator, the lower the number of atoms.

amu (atomic mass unit) is a convenient unit for measuring mass of atoms. If $m$ is the mass of an atom in amu, then the number of atoms in 1kg is:

$$\frac{1}{m} \frac{kg}{amu}=\frac{1}{m} N_A$$

$\frac{kg}{amu}=N_A$ is a constant called Avogadro number